# Restarting a service after a fatal crash

Tags: c#, service, exception

I have several services that run correctly 99.9% of the time. However, they work with network and database and occasionally an error that I have not anticipated makes it into the code and causes the service to crash. In this instance, restarting the service usually fixes the problem.

My service creates a new thread where the main code is run. I have added error handling to the service class that catches and logs any unhandled exceptions from this thread. What I am wondering is if I can call OnStop and then OnStart from the service class to restart my service?

The code that I am using is in located in the same class as OnStart and OnStop. I have posted it below:

```
private void ExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        log.Append("Fatal Exception:\n" + args.ExceptionObject);
        eventLog.WriteEntry(log.ToString());
        log = new StringBuilder();

        OnStop();

        if (numberOfCrashes++ < 10)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(60000);
            OnStart(null);

            log.Append("The service has been restarted " + numberOfCrashes + " times.");
            eventLog.WriteEntry(log.ToString());
            log = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am wondering is if I can call OnStop and then OnStart from the
>   service class to restart my service?

This will depend on *how* you've implemented your `OnStart` and `OnStop` logic.

For example, if your `OnStart` is able to determine if the working thead is already started and, if so, it stops and starts it again, then yes, you may be able to simulate a service restart by directly calling these methods.

Thus, your actual code on `OnStart` and `OnStop` is the right answer to your question, and it's up to you to refactor it to cover your requirement of programatically-restarting your service without restarting the service at the operating system level.